# OpenXML- Set a slide layout for a slide in presentation

Tags: powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk, presentation, presentationml

Here is the code i used to create the presentation.

What i'm trying here is to create a slide and insert shapes into it and attach the slide into already created presentation. That works fine.

My question is **how i set the layout the of the inserted slide.** what i mean slide layout here is

```
slideLayoutpart.SlideLayout = new SlideLayout() {
    Type = SlideLayoutValues.VerticalTitleAndText
};
```

I want to set this layout to my Slide.

I had looked working with slidelayout [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278311(v=office.15).aspx)

```
Slide slide = new Slide(new CommonSlideData(new ShapeTree()));

uint drawingObjectId = 1;

// Construct the slide content.            
// Specify the non-visual properties of the new slide.
NonVisualGroupShapeProperties nonVisualProperties = slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree.AppendChild(new NonVisualGroupShapeProperties());
nonVisualProperties.NonVisualDrawingProperties = new NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = 1, Name = "" };
nonVisualProperties.NonVisualGroupShapeDrawingProperties = new NonVisualGroupShapeDrawingProperties();
nonVisualProperties.ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties = new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties();

// Specify the group shape properties of the new slide.
slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree.AppendChild(new GroupShapeProperties());

// Declare and instantiate the title shape of the new slide. TITLE SHAPE
Shape titleShape = slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree.AppendChild(new Shape());
drawingObjectId++;

// Specify the required shape properties for the title shape. 
NonVisualShapeProperties nonVisualShapeProperties2;
ShapeProperties shapeProperties2;

CreateVisualProperties(out nonVisualShapeProperties2, out shapeProperties2,
    PlaceholderValues.Title, drawingObjectId);

// Specify the text of the title shape.
TextBody titletextBody = CreateContent(slideTitle, PlaceholderValues.Title);

titleShape.Append(nonVisualShapeProperties2);
titleShape.Append(shapeProperties2);
titleShape.Append(titletextBody);


// Save the new slide part.
slide.Save(slidePart);

#region Slide Poistioning

// The slide ID list should not be null.
SlideIdList slideIdList = presentationPart.Presentation.SlideIdList;

// Find the highest slide ID in the current list.
uint maxSlideId = 1;
SlideId prevSlideId = null;


foreach (SlideId slideId in slideIdList.ChildElements)
{

    if (slideId.Id > maxSlideId)
    {
        maxSlideId = slideId.Id;
    }

    position--;
    if (position == 0)
    {
        prevSlideId = slideId;
    }

}

maxSlideId++;

// Get the ID of the previous slide.
SlidePart lastSlidePart;

if (prevSlideId != null)
{
    //Changed to set first thing as layout
    // lastSlidePart = (SlidePart)presentationPart.GetPartById(((SlideId)(slideIdList.ChildElements[0])).RelationshipId);
    lastSlidePart = (SlidePart)presentationPart.GetPartById(prevSlideId.RelationshipId);
}
else
{
    lastSlidePart = (SlidePart)presentationPart.GetPartById(((SlideId)(slideIdList.ChildElements[0])).RelationshipId);
}

// Use the same slide LAYOUT HERE as that of the previous slide.
if (null != lastSlidePart.SlideLayoutPart)
{
    SlideLayoutPart slideLayoutpartNew = lastSlidePart.SlideLayoutPart;
    slideLayoutpartNew.AddNewPart<SlideMasterPart>();
    slideLayoutpartNew.SlideLayout = new SlideLayout() { Type = SlideLayoutValues.VerticalTitleAndText };
    slidePart.AddPart(slideLayoutpartNew);

    slidePart.AddPart(slideLayoutPart);

    //When i try to set lastslidelayout it works fine.
    //slidePart.AddPart(lastSlidePart.SlideLayoutPart);
}

// Insert the new slide into the slide list after the previous slide.
SlideId newSlideId = slideIdList.InsertAfter(new SlideId(), prevSlideId);
newSlideId.Id = maxSlideId;
newSlideId.RelationshipId = presentationPart.GetIdOfPart(slidePart);
#endregion

// Save the modified presentation.
presentationPart.Presentation.Save();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out ,How to set layout

```
 string layoutName = "Title and Content";

        // Get SlideMasterPart and SlideLayoutPart from the existing Presentation Part
        SlideMasterPart slideMasterPart = presentationPart.SlideMasterParts.First();
        SlideLayoutPart slideLayoutPart = slideMasterPart.SlideLayoutParts.SingleOrDefault
            (sl => sl.SlideLayout.CommonSlideData.Name.Value.Equals(layoutName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        if (slideLayoutPart == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("The slide layout " + layoutName + " is not found");
        }

        slidePart.AddPart<SlideLayoutPart>(slideLayoutPart);
```

**I'm here appending the layout to slidepart and will save the presentation**