# C# OpenXML SDK - Inserting a new slide from slide masters

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am attempting to implement the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076114/c-sharp-openxml-sdk-2-5-insert-new-slide-from-slide-masters-with-the-layout/34500170) and/or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504305/openxml-set-a-slide-layout-for-a-slide-in-presentation).

I have a .pptx file that contains zero slides initially. One of the layouts is named "One content". For now, I just want to produce a new PPTX file with a single slide based on this layout. Should be trivial, no? No, apparently not.

In file **OpenXmlUtils.cs** I have the following method which I use to create a new PPTX from the "template" file:

```
public static void CopyTemplate(string template, string target)
{
    string targetPath = Path.GetFullPath(target);
    string targetFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(targetPath);
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetFolder))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetFolder);
    }
    System.IO.File.Copy(template, targetPath, true);
}
```

My **PPTWriter.cs** broken down to MCVE:

```
public PPTOpenXMLWriter(string templatePath, string presSaveAsPath)
{
    if (File.Exists(presSaveAsPath)) { File.Delete(presSaveAsPath); }

    OpenXmlUtils.CopyTemplate(templatePath, presSaveAsPath);

    _createPresentation(presSaveAsPath);

}

private void _createPresentation(string presSaveAsPath)
{
    using (PresentationDocument presentationDocument = PresentationDocument.Open(presSaveAsPath, true))
    {

        string layoutName = "One content";

        _insertNewSlide(presentationDocument.PresentationPart, layoutName);

        presentationDocument.Save();
    }
}    

private void _insertNewSlide(PresentationPart presentationPart, string layoutName)
{
    Slide slide = new Slide(new CommonSlideData(new ShapeTree()));
    SlidePart slidePart = presentationPart.AddNewPart<SlidePart>();
    slide.Save(slidePart);
    SlideMasterPart slideMasterPart = presentationPart.SlideMasterParts.FirstOrDefault();
    SlideLayoutPart slideLayoutPart = slideMasterPart.SlideLayoutParts.SingleOrDefault
            (sl => sl.SlideLayout.CommonSlideData.Name.Value.Equals(layoutName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    slidePart.AddPart<SlideLayoutPart>(slideLayoutPart);
    slidePart.Slide.CommonSlideData = (CommonSlideData)slideLayoutPart.SlideLayout.CommonSlideData.Clone();

    SlideIdList slideIdList = null;
    if ( presentationPart.Presentation.SlideIdList is null)
    {
        presentationPart.Presentation.SlideIdList = new SlideIdList();
    }
    slideIdList = presentationPart.Presentation.SlideIdList;
    // find the highest id
    uint maxSlideId = 0;
    if (slideIdList.ChildElements.Count() > 0)
        maxSlideId = slideIdList.ChildElements
            .Cast<SlideId>()
            .Max(x => x.Id.Value);

    // Insert the new slide into the slide list after the previous slide.
    SlideId newSlideId = new SlideId();
    slideIdList.Append(newSlideId);
    newSlideId.Id = maxSlideId;
    newSlideId.RelationshipId = presentationPart.GetIdOfPart(slidePart);

    // Save the modified presentation.
    presentationPart.Presentation.Save();
}
```

The resulting file is corrupt and needs to be "repaired" by PowerPoint, after which repair process the slide layout is **not** the layout that was specified. In fact it's a completely different layout with a radically different XML structure and all I can gather is that it's somehow defaulting back to the ordinally *first* layout in the master ("Title"), because it doesn't know how to handle whatever it's actually been given via OpenXML.

This seems like it ought to be a fairly common use-case, and perhaps my expectations are wrong, but it seems like given an *already existing* slide layout, you ought to be able to (relatively easily) create a new slide *based on that layout* which will contain all of the same placeholder shapes, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Got it. The following is working for my test scenarios (thanks to your code for help):

```
    presentationPart.InsertNewSlide("CV Full page");
    presentationPart.InsertNewSlide("CV Half page");
    presentationPart.InsertNewSlide("Credential full page");
    presentationPart.InsertNewSlide("CV or Credential 5 to a page", 3);

    public static void InsertNewSlide(this PresentationPart presentationPart, string layoutName, int? position = null)
    {
        Slide slide = new Slide();
        SlidePart slidePart = presentationPart.AddNewPart<SlidePart>();
        slide.Save(slidePart);

        SlideMasterPart slideMasterPart = presentationPart.SlideMasterParts.FirstOrDefault();
        SlideLayoutPart slideLayoutPart = slideMasterPart.GetSlideLayoutPartByLayoutName(layoutName);

        slidePart.AddPart(slideLayoutPart, slideMasterPart.GetIdOfPart(slideLayoutPart));
        slidePart.Slide.CommonSlideData = (CommonSlideData)slideLayoutPart.SlideLayout.CommonSlideData.Clone();

        string id = slideMasterPart.GetIdOfPart(slideLayoutPart);
        slidePart.CloneSlideLayout(slideLayoutPart, id);

        slideMasterPart.AddPart(slideLayoutPart, id);
        presentationPart.SetSlideID(slidePart, position);
    }

    public static void SetSlideID(this PresentationPart presentationPart, SlidePart slidePart, int? position = null)
    {
        SlideIdList slideIdList = presentationPart.Presentation.SlideIdList;
        if (slideIdList == null)
        {
            slideIdList = new SlideIdList();
            presentationPart.Presentation.SlideIdList = slideIdList;
        }

        if (position != null && position > slideIdList.Count())
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unable to set slide to position '{position}'. There are only '{slideIdList.Count()}' slides.");

        uint newId = slideIdList.ChildElements.Count() == 0 ? 256 : slideIdList.GetMaxSlideId() + 1;
        if (position == null)
        {
            var newSlideId = slideIdList.AppendChild(new SlideId());
            newSlideId.Id = newId;
            newSlideId.RelationshipId = presentationPart.GetIdOfPart(slidePart);
        }
        else
        {
            SlideId nextSlideId = (SlideId)slideIdList.ChildElements[position.Value - 1];
            var newSlideId = slideIdList.InsertBefore(new SlideId(), nextSlideId);
            newSlideId.Id = newId;
            newSlideId.RelationshipId = presentationPart.GetIdOfPart(slidePart);
        }
    }

    public static uint GetMaxSlideId(this SlideIdList slideIdList)
    {
        uint maxSlideId = 0;
        if (slideIdList.ChildElements.Count() > 0)
            maxSlideId = slideIdList.ChildElements
                .Cast<SlideId>()
                .Max(x => x.Id.Value);
        return maxSlideId;
    }

    public static SlideLayoutPart GetSlideLayoutPartByLayoutName(this SlideMasterPart slideMasterPart, string layoutName)
    {
        return slideMasterPart.SlideLayoutParts.SingleOrDefault
                (sl => sl.SlideLayout.CommonSlideData.Name.Value.Equals(layoutName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }

    public static void CloneSlideLayout(this SlidePart newSlidePart, SlideLayoutPart slPart, string id)
    {
        /* ensure we added the rel ID to this part */
        newSlidePart.AddPart(slPart, id);
        using (Stream stream = slPart.GetStream()) { newSlidePart.SlideLayoutPart.FeedData(stream); }

        newSlidePart.Slide.CommonSlideData = (CommonSlideData)slPart.SlideLayout.CommonSlideData.Clone();

        foreach (ImagePart iPart in slPart.ImageParts)
            newSlidePart.AddPart(iPart, slPart.GetIdOfPart(iPart));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed some discrepancies in the slide's `.rels`, from the correct, manually produced slide:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
    <Relationship Target="../slideLayouts/slideLayout8.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/slideLayout" Id="rId1"/>
</Relationships>
```

And the incorrect one looked like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
<Relationship Id="R522c7c9989a04964" Target="/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout8.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/slideLayout"/>
<Relationship Id="rId5" Target="/ppt/media/image2.bin" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image"/>
</Relationships>
```

Two discrepancies, which I believe are as follows:

- The `image2.bin` I believe I traced this back to a 1x1 pixel autoshape "object" that was present on several of the slide masters. I manually removed that from each slide master where it existed, and resaved my template pptx file.
- The slide is missing the rel **ID** back to the slide layout, seems easy enough. I added some extension methods to the OpenXmlUtils class, and modified the `_insertNewSlide` method as follows:

```
private void _insertNewSlide(PresentationPart presentationPart, string layoutName)
{
    Slide slide = new Slide();
    SlidePart slidePart = presentationPart.AddNewPart<SlidePart>();

    slide.Save(slidePart);
    SlideMasterPart slideMasterPart = presentationPart.SlideMasterParts.FirstOrDefault();
    SlideLayoutPart slideLayoutPart = slideMasterPart.GetSlideLayoutPartByLayoutName(layoutName); // extension method

    /* ensure we added the rel ID to this part */
    slidePart.AddPart<SlideLayoutPart>(slideLayoutPart, slideMasterPart.GetIdOfPart(slideLayoutPart));

    slidePart.Slide.CommonSlideData = (CommonSlideData)slideLayoutPart.SlideLayout.CommonSlideData.Clone();

    slidePart.CloneSlideLayout(slideLayoutPart); // extension method

    presentationPart.AppendSlide(slidePart); // extension method

}
```

I've added the following extension methods in **OpenXmlUtils.cs**:

```
public static void CloneSlideLayout(this SlidePart newSlidePart, SlideLayoutPart slPart, string id)
{
    // creates a Slide from a SlideLayout

    /* ensure we added the rel ID to this part */
    newSlidePart.AddPart(slPart, id);
    using (Stream stream = slPart.GetStream()) { newSlidePart.SlideLayoutPart.FeedData(stream); }

    newSlidePart.Slide.CommonSlideData = (CommonSlideData)slPart.SlideLayout.CommonSlideData.Clone();

    foreach (ImagePart iPart in slPart.ImageParts)
    {
        newSlidePart.AddPart<ImagePart>(iPart, slPart.GetIdOfPart(iPart));
    }

}

public static uint GetNextSlideId(this SlideIdList slideIdList)
{
    uint nextId;
    uint maxId = GetMaxSlideId(slideIdList);
    if (maxId == 0)
    {
        // Slide Id must be >= 256
        nextId = 256;
    }
    else
    {
        nextId = maxId++;
    }
    return nextId;
}
public static uint GetMaxSlideId(this SlideIdList slideIdList)
{

    // find the highest id
    uint maxSlideId = 0;
    if (slideIdList.ChildElements.Count() > 0)
        maxSlideId = slideIdList.ChildElements
            .Cast<SlideId>()
            .Max(x => x.Id.Value);
    return maxSlideId;
}
public static SlideLayoutPart GetSlideLayoutPartByLayoutName(this SlideMasterPart slideMasterPart, string layoutName)
{
    return slideMasterPart.SlideLayoutParts.SingleOrDefault
            (sl => sl.SlideLayout.CommonSlideData.Name.Value.Equals(layoutName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}

public static void AppendSlide(this PresentationPart presentationPart, SlidePart newSlidePart)
{
        SlideMasterPart slideMasterPart = presentationPart.SlideMasterParts.FirstOrDefault();
        SlideLayoutPart slideLayoutPart = slideMasterPart.GetSlideLayoutPartByLayoutName(layoutName);

        Slide slide = new Slide(  );
        SlidePart slidePart = presentationPart.AddNewPart<SlidePart>();
        slide.Save(slidePart);

        string id = slideMasterPart.GetIdOfPart(slideLayoutPart);
        slidePart.CloneSlideLayout(slideLayoutPart, id);

        presentationPart.AppendSlide(slidePart); 
}
```

Having implemented these changes, I can successfully produce the "One content" slide from the master, and it looks like *most* of the other layouts are output correctly as well, but if I try to create an instance of each slide layout, there is still a "repair" issue which I'll need to isolate.

**Update**:

Comment: I'm trying to do the same kind of thing. Thought i'd better let you know that your code doesn't compile.

Comment: good luck. I never was able to figure out out and abandoned the C# approach in favor of the python-pptx library .